# Makefile calling different program from the rule

Tags: makefile

I have a make file to build a simple pascal compiler using bison and flex, but when I run make from terminal it shows that yacc is being called instead of bison.

My Makefile:

```
all: minipascal

minipascal.tab.h minipascal.tab.c: minipascal.y 
    bison -r all -d minipascal.y

minipascal.flex.c: minipascal.l minipascal.tab.h
    flex -o minipascal.flex.c minipascal.l

calc: minipascal.c minipascal.tab.c minipascal.lex.c
   gcc minipascal.flex.c minipascal.tab.c minipascal.c -lf -o minipascal >& buildlog.txt

clean:
    rm minipascal.tab.h minipascal.tab.c minipascal.lex.c buildlog.txt minipascal minipascal.output
```

I have bison in my path and the build works as expected when I type the commands line by line. The files minipascal.h and minipascal.c exist within the current directory where I run make.

Output from the make command:

```
yacc  minipascal.y 
yacc: e - line 73 of "minipascal.y", syntax error
            %empty                                                                  {$$ = NULL;}
            ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'minipascal.c' failed
make: *** [minipascal.c] Error 1
```

Comment: Run `make -d` to see which implicit rule is invoking `yacc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really not a good idea to have a source file called `foo.c` if you also have source files named `foo.y` or `foo.l`. make will cheerfully overwrite `foo.c`, leaving you scrambling for a backup. (You do have backups, right?). If you want to use an additional source file and you don't want to think up a different name, then use an additional suffix, like `foo.base.c`. (Or you can use an explicit empty rule, as mentioned below. But IMHO it's safe to avoid the problem.)

Any file named in a makefile, whether as a target or a prerequisite, is considered by make to be potentially buildable. Since `minipascal.c` is listed as a prerequisite, that means that `minipascal.c` is on make's list of files it is prepared to build.

It's true that you don't have any build rules for `minipascal.c`. But make knows how to build `%.c` from either `%.y` or `%.l` (<kbd>%</kbd> is a wildcard character; it will be substituted with the same string in the target and the prerequisite.)

When make sees that it needs `minipascal.c`, it first does a check to see if there is an explicit recipe for that file (there isn't) and then it looks through its default database of recipes. Here it finds both the `%.y → %.c` recipe and the `%.l → %.c` recipe. Luckily for you, the `.y` recipe came first in its database, so it tried that. And even more luckily, the recipe failed without modifying the "target" `minipascal.c`, because the recipe is:

```
%.c: %.y
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(YACC.y) $< 
        mv -f y.tab.c $@
```

and the non-zero exit code from `yacc` caused the recipe to terminate without executing the `mv` command. The .l recipe is:

```
%.c: %.l
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        @$(RM) $@ 
        $(LEX.l) $< > $@
```

In case the symbols are not obvious, that would work out to:

```
@rm minipascal.c
lex minipascal.l > minipascal.c
```

where the `@` means that the `rm` command will not be echoed to the screen. Not that it makes much difference, because the redirect in the `lex` command would also delete minipascal.c, even if `lex` failed.

Of course, make doesn't *unconditionally* attempt to rebuild `minipascal.c`. It first checks the timestamps to make sure that the rebuild is necessary. Having decided to use the `%.y` rule to build `minipascal.c`, it compares the timestamps of `minipascal.c` and `minipascal.y`. It decided to rebuild `minipascal.c` because the bison source was more recent, so it assumes that the `minipascal.c` file was out-of-date.

---

As it happens, your `all` rule depends on `minipascal` but there is no rule to build `minipascal`. There is a rule to build `calc` but make cannot know that you meant `minipascal`.

That doesn't stop make, though, since it knows how to build `minipascal` from `minipascal.c` (using yet another default rule). Having decided to do that, it then proceeds to verify that `minipascal.c` is up-to-date, as above. Had it decided that `minipascal.c` was up-to-date, it would have then built `minipascal` using its default build rule, which would also fail with linker errors, since neither the parser nor the lexer (nor your `-lf` library) are in the default build rule.

Your makefile also inconsistently uses `minipascal.flex.c` and `minipascal.lex.c`. That will also cause you grief.

---

If you really want to have a source file called `minipascal.c`, then you need to protect it from automatic building by providing an empty build rule:

```
minipascal.c: ;
```

But, as I said, that is probably not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks @rici, it was exactly the problem. I was using another makefile as a model and I didn't notice some of the errors appointed by you. I followed your suggestion for rename the files and fortunately make didn't overwrite minipascal.c. But I'm using git to versioning the code, it wouldn't be a problem at all, but it's better to avoid some problems.